# C#/SQL Checking for duplicate entries

Tags: c#, duplicates

I am working on a project, and I have hit a brick wall. My code adds dates with a type to a database, but I need to create an error when there is already a similar entry within the code. However, I cannot get my loop to check for duplicates, and instead it adds duplicates! I am not very good at loops so I'm a bit stuck at this. Any help to check for duplicate entries and to stop it from creating too many would be a great help! Changed my code within this text area so it's not exactly the same variable names.

Here is my code: -

```
if (DT != null && DT.Length > 0 || DF != null && DF.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int t = 0; t < Type.Length; t++)
                {
                    DateTime checkDate;

                    if (Type.IsSelectionValid(8, out typeError) && DateTime.TryParse(DF, out typeError) && DateTime.TryParse(DT, out checkDate))
                    {
                            TypeValid = true;
                            error.Error = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            error.Errors = "Type-Invalid";
                            absenceTypeValid = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        error.Errors = "Type-Duplicate";
                        TypeValid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for [How to remove duplicate rows from a table in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139444)

Comment: No, it isn't. I don't understand why my loop is creating duplicates, and I need it to stop a user from adding duplicates. Thank you for attempting to help though.

Comment: I don't see any duplicate checking in the code you have posted, can you add comments or explain in your question where the duplicate check(that is not working) code is ?

Comment: It is adding duplicates at the (dF.Date) if loop part. I have deleted this part now, and I shall see what happens. However, I need it to check for duplicates, and if so, I want it to not post anything. But I am not sure what to add to my code to do this.

Comment: Can you post code for Type, if not for the entire class, can you just post for Type.IsSelectionValid

Comment: You might add some line by line comments to your code so we can see what you're thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm 'fairly' sure you are going out of your way to make a problem more difficult than it is here, but I can't say for sure since I'm not entirely sure what this is doing.

But here are the conditions that need to be met to get to your Type-Duplicate Error line:

1) Either DT or DF have to not be empty to get past the first if statement

2) Either IsSelectionValid() has to return false or either DT or DF have to be an invalid DateTime.

None of those things constitute a duplicate.

Let me try to explain what I see here:

I first see variables called DT, DF.  I can see these are dates, but that's all I know about them.  I see 'Type' which I understand even less about than DT and DF.  I see that you are doing a loop for Type.Length number of iterations... but what does this mean to me if I don't have a clue what Type is?

If you had comments explaining what things are I 'might' be able to help you, but there's just really not enough information to know what's happening here.

If you simply want to know how to avoid adding duplicates to a database, then I would suggest adding a constraint or index to the column in the database and then you can just catch the exceptions that are thrown when you try to insert a duplicate and deal with it that way.  Alternatively, account for it in your insert statement.

Comment: I know what is causing the duplicate now, and I have rid of this. I shall update my post accordingly. What I am trying to do now is to make sure that my code checks for duplicates and does not post these to the database.

Comment: Your code isn't quite making sense.  You have a loop that increments the variable t, but t is never used in your loop... it just the same thing every time.

Secondly, I don't see any code that inserts data into a database.  How can you know if there's a dupe here when you can't see what's already in the db table?  That check has to be part of your sql query, or part of the command from whatever framework your using to interface to the db, right?

Comment: It does add to my database, if it's any easier, how do I create a loop that checks that someone isn't adding something twice? There is a lot more code that this, but I just put the loop part as this was the part I was stuck on.

Comment: @BrandonMoore exactly what i was thinking, but i wanted to see what is inside `Type.IsSelectionValid` before i could say so

Comment: @kellehbeans Let's say your program only has one item to add to the database, but that item is already in the database.  How will this help you catch it?

Comment: bool typeValid = type.IsSelectionValid(8, out typeError);

Comment: I am using a dictionary now, so far so good. I realised my duplicate fault was in another area of code, so sorry about that.